# How can I create a REST server with better authentication than basic?

Tags: delphi, datasnap, delphi-10.3-rio

I have created a REST server using Delphi Rio.

This server uses basic authentication; it looks like this kind of authentication is the default one on Delphi, but I was wondering how can I use a better authentication method, for example with a token or with OAuth? Or do you have any other advice?

I tried to find some guides but all I can find is the basic auth.

For example these:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Tutorial:_Using_a_REST_DataSnap_Server_with_an_Application
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Authentication_and_Authorization

Thank you!

Comment: Define what "better" means. And OAuth is not an authentication protocol ("auth" means "authorization" here).

Comment: I might be wrong so I'm asking here. I have read that it's not a good idea to use that kind of authentication mostly because it's not encrypted? for example this: https://blog.restcase.com/4-most-used-rest-api-authentication-methods/ but I cannot find any guide regarding the use of the token for example...

Comment: If you use SSL, the login/password is encrypted.

Comment: Ok but just to understand, why in that website (and many other) I've seen this kind of sentences? "HTTP Basic Authentication is rarely recommended due to its inherent security vulnerabilities." That is what I meant with "better"..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think bearer is better than basic, because the client dont need to use "user and password" all the time, it uses token, you can use one JWT to build your token. But delphi dont have JWT solution with Datasnap, you need to do yourself or one option is DMVC Framework, it already has one solution with JWT, look for it on git hub. However, in this case you will need to choose DMVC or DataSnap to build your End Points, or look for some independent classes to build JWT yourself.